# Measure theory with algebraic point of view

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, von-neumann-algebras

When I was reading one mathematician's blog (I forgot his name by now), I encountered with the opinion that the measure theory should be studied without any $\sigma$-algebras and so on. Instead one should use the language of commutative Von Neuman algebras. I am not suggesting to discuss this opinion I rather want to ask if there are some textbooks treating measure theory in such a way.

Comment: I would guess that the person who advocated this point of view is the one who wrote [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49426/is-there-a-category-structure-one-can-place-on-measure-spaces-so-that-category-t/49542#49542).

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite the full treatment that you might want. But $\textit{Analysis Now}$ by Gert Pedersen has a chapter at the end where he develops measure theory by starting with positive linear functions on spaces of functions and getting Radon measures afterwards.